# How to force child of class to override field with child of field's type?

Tags: c#, oop, generics, inheritance, overriding

Sorry about the confusing title, I had no idea how to describe this question in one sentence. I have a parent class EmergencyWorker with 2 children:

```
public abstract class EmergencyWorker
{
    protected virtual Vehicle vehicle;
}

public class EMT : EmergencyWorker
{
    protected override Ambulance vehicle;
}

public class Firefighter : EmergencyWorker
{ 
    protected override FireTruck vehicle;
}
```

Ambulance and FireTruck are both Vehicles.
I want it so that every vehicle that belonging to an EMT is always an ambulance, and every vehicle belonging to a firefighter is always a firetruck.

Virtual and Override don't work for this as I am getting "modifier 'override' is not valid for this item"
I'm not very experience with generics but I suspect they may be helpful here.

So how do I force the children of EmergencyWorker to override the vehicle field with a child of Vehicle type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would do that with generic type parameters.

```
public abstract class EmergencyWorker<T> where T : Vehicle
{
    protected T vehicle;
}

public class EMT : EmergencyWorker<Ambulance>
{
}

public class Firefighter : EmergencyWorker<FireTruck>
{ 
}
```

Comment: Awesome, this was perfect. Thank you.